# How to handle Java InterruptedException without business logic break?

Tags: java, semaphore, interrupted-exception

First of all I read other question about this item and know how to use `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

But the problem is that I need my business logic to be done even if this exception occurred.
As far as I understand  "InterruptedException" is a situation when the OS ask my thread to stop execution for some time, and after this time thread could proceed execution.
I use a `semaphore.acquire()` and I want to retry "acquire" action if "InterruptedException" exception  occurred.
My code looks like this:

```
  private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
  ...

  private StorageConnection allocateConnection() {
        boolean allocated = false;
        while( !allocated ){
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                allocated = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        StorageConnection connection = connectionQueue.poll();
        // OTHER LOGIC
        return connection;
    }
```

Please, let me know if it is a correct way to handle this situation or what should I do if it is not ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt will come from some other place in your program. It's not something the OS is going to do of its own volition.

Typically interrupts indicate that the code should get out of there. This could be handled by throwing a more appropriate exception.

Currently your code, once interrupted, will keep interrupting itself. This is solvable by keeping the interrupt state in a local flag.

```
private StorageConnection allocateConnection() {
    boolean interrupted = false;
    boolean allocated = false;
    while( !allocated ){
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            allocated = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupted = true;
        }
    }

    StorageConnection connection = connectionQueue.poll();
    // OTHER LOGIC

    if (interrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

It is not an entirely unreasonable attitude to simply clear and ignore the interrupt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this solution doesn't work for me as a "semaphore" must be acquired, otherwise I will get concurrency issue.

Comment: @АлександрСергеевичДжус The while loop above only exits once the semaphore is acquired. The code just restores the interrupt state before exiting.